# What is the tidyeval way of using dplyr::filter?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

Call the function below using `foo(c("b"))`. The outputs are shown inline.

What is the right way of writing `df %>% filter(!!x  > (!!x))`?

I have included an example of using `mutate` in tidyeval style to contrast it with `filter`.

```
foo <- function(variables) {

  x <- rlang::sym(variables[[1]])

  print(x)
  #> b

  print(typeof(x))
  #> [1] "symbol"

  df <- data_frame(a = 1, b = 2)

  print(df %>% mutate(!!x := 100 + !!x))

  #> # A tibble: 1 x 2
  #>         a     b
  #>       <dbl> <dbl>
  #>   1     1   102  

  print(df %>% filter(!!x  > (!!x)))

  #> Error in !x : invalid argument type

  print(df %>% filter(magrittr::is_greater_than(!!x, !!x)))

  #> # A tibble: 0 x 2
  #> # ... with 2 variables: a <dbl>, b <dbl>

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most of the way there except for a minor typo, the round brackets in your filter statement should be on the variable and not the value.

```
print(df %>% filter((!!x) > !!x))

#> # A tibble: 0 x 2
#> # ... with 2 variables: a <dbl>, b <dbl>
```

Comment: Maybe it's best to enclose on both sides, for consistency: `(!! x) > (!! y)`.

Comment: @lionel, what is the purpose of doing that? There is no `y` defined and those brackets will invalidate the argument.

Comment: What's the purpose of comparing `x` with `x`? What do you mean that by "brackets will invalidate the argument"?

Comment: I think lionel was referring to the first version of my post where I had a `y`. Regarding comparing `x` with `x` - that's just a dummy example I created to avoid using another variable

Comment: I'l go ahead and accept this answer. Also see @lionel's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46093640/1094109 to understand operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: All of this no longer applies. The precedence tree is reorganised so that `!!x + !!y` etc do the right thing by default. The parentheses are no longer necessary since rlang 0.2.0.

---

The `!` operator has really low precedence. This means that it will apply to most of the expression appearing on its right.

```
!! x > 3
```

is implicitly equivalent to:

```
(!! x > 3)
```

So you have to help R figure out the right precedence with explicit parentheses:

```
(!! x) > 3
```

Note that in most cases if you're unquoting on both sides of an operator, you technically don't have to apply the parentheses on the last one:

```
(!! x) + (!! y) + z
```

However that will vary according to often mysterious rules of precedence, so I suggest to always enclose in parentheses when operators are involved:

```
(!! x ) + (!! y) + (!! z)
```

Comment: I'll have to go with @kevin.arseneau 's answer because it worked out of the box but thanks a lot for explaining this! It is going to take a while to get used to this operator! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter_at`

```
oof <- function(variables) {
  x <- rlang::sym(variables[[1]])
  df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)
  print(df %>% filter_at(vars(!!x), any_vars(. == !!x)))
  print(df %>% filter(magrittr::equals(!!x, !!x)))
}
```

I use `magrittr::equals` to show the magrittr style works as well

```
oof(c("b"))

#   a b
# 1 1 2
#   a b
# 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic way of handling any field value condition

```
data%>%
    filter(!!quo((!!as.name (field1)) > (!!myVal)))
```