# Throw error when not in dplyr tidyeval

Tags: r, dplyr, nse, tidyeval

I'm using `dplyr` and trying out tidy evaluation.  I'm confused on how to check to make sure someone put in a bare object versus a string for NSE.  For example, I would like to filter on non-missing data:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df = data_frame(
  myvar = c(rep("yes", 2), NA)
)
myfun <- function(x){
  x = enquo(x)
  num = df %>%
    filter(!is.na( !! x)) 
  return(num)
}

myfun(myvar)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   myvar
#>   <chr>
#> 1 yes  
#> 2 yes
```

I would like the string equivalent to fail if possible.  This currently gives the "wrong" result as `is.na("myvar")` is never FALSE.

```r
myfun("myvar") # wrong result
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   myvar
#>   <chr>
#> 1 yes  
#> 2 yes  
#> 3 <NA>
```

After looking at [What is the tidyeval way of using dplyr::filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46086755/what-is-the-tidyeval-way-of-using-dplyrfilter), it seems like `filter_at` will allow for both scenarios to work fine:

```r
myfun <- function(x){
  x = enquo(x)
  num = df %>%
    filter_at(vars( !! x), all_vars(!is.na(.)))
  return(num)
}

myfun(myvar)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   myvar
#>   <chr>
#> 1 yes  
#> 2 yes
myfun("myvar") # correct result
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   myvar
#>   <chr>
#> 1 yes  
#> 2 yes
```

But is there a way to have `myfun("myvar")` fail?  I can't use `colnames()` and if statements as the unquoted expressions fail in that unless maybe using `as.name`.

Answer (score 3):

You can test for string literals with something like this

```
myfun <- function(x){
  x = enquo(x)
  stopifnot(!is.character(rlang::f_rhs(x)))
  num = df %>%
    filter(!is.na( !! x)) 
  return(num)
}
```

Since quosures are quite similar to formulas, the `rlang::f_rhs` part extracts the "thing" passed in so you can check what kind of language element it is. Perhaps instead of checking for a string, you might just want to make sure it's a symbol. You can do that with

```
myfun <- function(x){
  x = enquo(x)
  stopifnot(rlang::quo_is_symbol(x))
  num = df %>%
    filter(!is.na( !! x)) 
  return(num)
}
```

Then these do what you want

```
myfun(myvar) #works
myfun("myvar") #error
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer and fits within the `tidyeval` framework very well.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could test `x` in your function before unquoting it. If you pass in `x` as a quoted string, then its length = 1 and the function will return `NA` or whatever failure condition you desire. If you (correctly) pass in an unquoted variable name, then `length` will fail (with `Error: object 'knockdown' not found`) but the error will be silenced by `try()` and the function will proceed as normal.

```
myfun <- function(x){
try({if (length(x) == 1) return(NA)}, silent = TRUE)
x = enquo(x)
  num = df %>%
    filter_at(vars( !! x), all_vars(!is.na(.)))
  return(num)
}

myfun(myvar)
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  myvar
  <chr>
1 yes  
2 yes  

myfun("myvar")
[1] NA
```